# how to change/make an environment in latex that writes a set of commands in the code writing window, like \begin{figure} does?

Tags: latex, environment, overleaf

When you write \begin{figure} in latex and press enter, it automatically writes this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
```

I want to change this so that it writes this instead:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
```

A minor change but this is an example to display the problem. I want to understand how to go about defining an environment which, when called, specifically writes a set of commands (like \centering \includegraphics[]{} \caption{}) in the code editor window that I can dynamically manipulate each time.

LMK if you need further explanation. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If you would switch to a local editor you could configure the auto completion. For example in texstudio, you can adjust it by editing the .cwl files.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks, I’ll look into that. Anyway I can do this in overleaf?

Comment: (Tom from Overleaf Support here) It's not currently possible to fine-tune the snippets. It's something we might look into some day, but I can't make any promises about it really. I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: @yo' I see. Well, thanks anyways!

Answer (score -1):

I would also suggest using the completions incorporated in Sublime Text if at some point you decide to work with several files in a more customizable environment. You can still compile the main file in the IDE that you find more convenient or also create a build system in sublime depending on your needs.